# Explain this problem with dispatch() and connect() in redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jsx

I'm watching this tutorial and the code below works perfectly in the video, but when I try it, I get 'dispatch is not defined' error. Why is this?

```
import React from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {removeExpense} from '../Actions/Actions'

const ListItem = ({id, description, note, amount, createdAt})=>(
    <div>
        <h5>{description}</h5>
        <p>Note: {note}</p>
        <p>Amount: {amount}</p>
        <p>Created @{createdAt}</p>
        <button onClick={()=>{dispatch(removeExpense(id))}}>remove</button>
        <br/>
    </div>
)

export default connect()(ListItem); //Just to inject dispatch()
```

The instructor is using redux v3.7.2, react-redux v5.0.5 react v15.
Now I know that if I approach it as below, I can fix the problem.

```
const ListItem = (props)=>(
    <div>
        <h5>{props.description}</h5>
        <p>Note: {props.note}</p>
        <p>Amount: {props.amount}</p>
        <p>Created @{props.createdAt}</p>
        <button onClick={()=>{props.dispatch(removeExpense(props.id))}}>remove</button>
        <br/>
    </div>
)
```

Why doesn't remove button work in the first code? Could it be the outdated versions of the libraries?

Comment: I'm surprised that the code works in the video as you show it here. There must be something different because I expect the exact error that you get.

Comment: Can you give a link to the video you are watching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix your first example by changing this line:

```
const ListItem = ({id, description, note, amount, createdAt})=>(
```

to

```
const ListItem = ({id, description, note, amount, createdAt, dispatch})=>(
```

Comment: This solved the problem. Apparently the video i was watching does the same, i watched it 100 times but somehow i miss that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your destructuring of props you've omitted the dispatch which is supposed to be passed down.

Either add it to your destructuring statement:

```
const ListItem = ({id, description, note, amount, createdAt, dispatch})=>(
```

or access it via `props`

```
<button onClick={()=>{props.dispatch(removeExpense(id))}}>remove</button>
```

Comment: Note that accessing via `props` requires declaring `props`. One way is how the OP shows in his second example.